# How to get the server name from within a controller?

Tags: nginx, cherrypy

I am using cherrypy and nginx in my project. My controller part look like this:

```
@cherrypy.expose
@named(name="get_playlist", path="/get_playlist"):
def get_playlist(self):
```

My nginx part looks like this:
    server {

```
    listen 80;
    server_name local-www.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://example;
        proxy_redirect default;
    }

}
```

Is there a way to get local-www.example.com from within my controller?

Answer (score 0):

How about getting the host from the headers?

```
cherrpy.request.headers['Host']
```

Comment: Thanks! But what if there is proxy_redirect? Using your method I can get `example` but what I really want to get is `local-www.example.com`